# Best way to launch applications from a bash script?

Tags: bash, debian, daemon

I'm writing a simple menu using the `dialog` utility in a bash script.

The idea is that the menu script will run in a screen session which I can connect to over SSH (or whatever else).

I want to then use the menu to start/stop applications running on the machine. For example there might be a menu item called "Start/Stop gEdit". When it's selected, one of two things could happen:

1. If gEdit is not currently running, it starts it
2. If gEdit *is* currently running, it stops it

My question is, what is the best way to launch (and close) applications from my bash script? This is on Debian.

**Edit:** Is upstart the right choice here? It seems weird to write an upstart script for something like gEdit.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK..
You can run/stop applications from bash script the same way you do it from command line.

`./` to run
`kill -9 pid` to close.

Debian now is using systemd Not upstart.

If you want to see if gedit is running in order to start/stop you can do something like `pgrep gedit`:

```
if [ pgrep gedit > 0 ]
echo "Something"
then
echo "Other thing"
```